# find binary files in windows

Tags: windows, file-management

Is there any way to search for executable files in windows when it has been renamed? Say a .exe file has been renamed to a .txt or a .jpeg extension.

Comment: @crudedude - you've got two accounts. This one (superuser.com/users/15411/crudedude) and the one used to post the answer (superuser.com/users/15719/crudedude). E-mail team@stackoverflow.com about getting them merged.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Unix `file` utility](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/), which can tell you what a file is based on its contents.  You will need either the [Cygwin environment](http://www.cygwin.com/) or a win32-port package like [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) or [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

Here's how `file` works:

```
# previously, e.exe was renamed to e.jpg
$ file e.jpg
e.jpg: MS-DOS executable PE  for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit
```

Obviously, you have to give `file` a filename (or list of filenames) as an argument(s).  You could do this with `find` if you know roughly where the file should be, by using `find` and a folder name:

```
$ find <foldername> -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file
```

If you combine this with `grep`, you can strip out the non-executables:

```
$ find e-0.02718 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep executable
e-0.02718/e.jpg:          MS-DOS executable PE  for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit
e-0.02718/e.linux:        ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
e-0.02718/e.sun4u56:      ELF 32-bit MSB executable, SPARC, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
e-0.02718/EXAMPLES:       Bourne shell script text executable
e-0.02718/makefile:       script text executable for make -f
```

**Cygwin** and **GnuWin32** both provide the `file` and `find` commands (via the `file` and `findutils` packages).

**UnxUtils** includes `find`, but I can't verify that the `file` command is included.  The package does not appear to be maintained, so GnuWin32 is probably a better option.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you OK, no.

still you could search for the filename...

BTW: why would you possibly change the extension of a EXE to txt, jpeg or so? There is no advantage of it and will lead in a txt matter to a bunch of unusable chars and jpeg to a 'cannot open'.

(i would change your tags, use something like 'exe' or 'search'

Comment: Binary files are not necessary extended with .exe...It could be that Firewalls, Filters etc. don't let .exe files pass, but if you rename it to .jpg, the Filter will be happy.

Comment: you could say it like that, but he's obviously talking about 'a .exe file...'. Yes, the filter will be happy with jpg, but ive done this stuff before and sometimes if you rename it back, it will not work.

Comment: Renaming a file does nothing to the contents, a simple rename wouldn't cause failure.

Comment: @phoshi: +1 correct.  a file that "will not work" after renaming, transferring, and renaming back ...has probably gotten mangled in transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a search using a specific enough portion within the targetted file (which is apparently known in that case) ; it might be very slow, depending on the amount of data to process, but theoretically no more than any solution which would specifically recognize EXE files according to their content. It may not work with Windows Explorer though, because searching inside files is possible only for a limited range of extensions (for example, I tried to locate a specific portion of dialogue in SRT subtitle files but couldn't find a match, yet there was indeed a file containing the relevant portion).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) to check the actual type of files and optionally change their extensions.